# How do I access a mobile mailserver on a mac as opposed to a web mailserver?

Tags: mac, mail.app, email

I have an iPad on which I can access my email through a mobile mail server. It all works fine. But when trying to access my mail through my mac there is a security problem of some sort that won't allow me to access my email. So I was thinking, since I can avoid this security problem on my iPad, is there a way for me to access the same server as I do on my iPad? Maybe not in Mail.app but perhaps Sparrow or equivalent?

Cheers for the help!

Comment: How do you connect to the mail-server?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, didn't see it. 

I use an email address, a server (mobile.company.com), domain (company.com), username, password. This all works fine on my iPad. But when I try to connect using my mac it wants me to use webmail.company.com not mobile.comapny.com. And that's where it stops working (because the webmail is a lot more restricted and what not)....any ideas??

Just surprised i can't get it to work on my mac when it works perfectly on my ipad....

Comment: How do you connect to the mail server on the IPad - you have said what you enter but not where which app/screen you use

Answer (score 1):

#### Via The Browser

You'd have to send a mobile user agent to the mobile.company.com (there's a redirect on desktop devices). Safari will get you there via User Agent in the developer tools. First turn on Developer Tools.

[image: How to turn on Developer Tools]

Then change the user agent.

[image: How to change the user agent]

Now you should be able to access mobile mail server as a mobile user: mobile.company.com. I'm not sure if your ISP provides a webmail interface for mobile users. If not, you won't see much there.

#### Potential Solution: Spoof User Agent in Desktop Email Client

I can't quickly find an email client which directly spoofs user agent. If I had to guess which ones might be capable of offering an alternative user agent, you could try either [MailMate](https://freron.com/) (powerful high configurable shareware) or [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) (geeky open source with an option for everything).

Contact info to MailMate creator Benny Kjær Nielsen is [here](https://freron.com/contact/).

#### Alternative Solution: Clean Up Your Mac's Certification Authorities

You may find it easier to reset your security certificates. Make sure Keychain Access is set up this way.

[image]

You should also delete expired or invalid certificates from under the System sidebar menu. Once you've done both of these things, you should run Software Update as Apple should replace some of the now missing certificates. Certificates and Signing Authorities can be imported by hand but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

I've just done this myself and it's allowed Chromium to load Github again. It may work with your email security issues as well. This is the lasting and flexible solution but perhaps the hardest to pin down.